# Where is the friction coming from in this simple setup?

Tags: physics, joints, hinge-joint

I'm creating a simple implementation of the classic cart and pole balancing control problem. I'd like to have a 2D interface with the cart and pendulum controlled by the Unity physics, so that I can implement a control algorithm.

I've created a new project, added a square and round 2D physic sprite. I've configured the cart to be restricted on a sliding joint, and the pendulum attached to the cart with a hinge joint. I'm trying to get the amount of friction to be absolutely zero, but I cannot seem to accomplish this. Note that I haven't written a line of code yet - I'm just trying to get the proper behavior first.

Here is what results from a static starting position. Notice that the pendulum appears to be losing energy. Following this are the configurations of the two game objects.

[image]

I've created a new Physics Material 2D and set the values to zero:

[image]

Here is the configuration of the cart sprite:

[image]
[image]

And the pendulum:

[image]

Comment: I notice you have applied angular drag to the pendulum, meaning a portion of its angular momentum will be sapped in each tick. Have you tried zeroing that out?

Comment: There's also a max angular velocity parameter (buried in physics settings, or settable through code) https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-maxAngularVelocity.html . If your pendulum tried to exceed that, its velocity will be capped.

Comment: @DMGregory No effect. I actually had that set to zero originally (it was the first thing I found). I then created the new material, and at some point the angular drag was reset to the default value. However, changing it again to zero (and still having my "No Friction" material) and I see a decaying pendulum. ("no effect" means there is still friction - perhaps it's been reduced slightly but I'm not sure. It's still definitely slowing)